# How to send a message to a kicked user in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to make discord.js send a message to a kicked user if they have been kicked from the corresponding server, but I'm getting this error when trying:

```
 DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Shushan\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Shushan\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/988657628710334484/messages',
  code: 50007,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

Can someone please help me on why this error is showing?

`kick.js`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 
  [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = 'plz ';


const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'This Command Kicks People!',
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            const f = String(memberTarget);
            newStr = f.replace('@', '');
            newStrTwo = newStr.replace('<', '');
            newStrThree = newStrTwo.replace('>', '');
            client.users.fetch(newStrThree).then((user) => {
                try {
                    user.send("txt");   ;
                } catch (err){
                    console.log("err");
                }
            })
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("This User Was Kicked Successfully.");
        }else{
            message.channel.send("This User Couldn't Be Kicked.");
        }
    }
}


client.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: You cant send a message to a person without being on their friends list (not applicable to bots), being in a server they're in (unless they've turned off "allow direct messages from this server"), or them granting your bot permissions via oauth (not sure if this exists but it probably does)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware, its not possible to do this, i recommend sending the message first then kicking the user shortly after. If you need a code snippet of that, let me know